# Magento 2 - get Excl. Tax, Incl. Tax label

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to switch positions of Excl and Incl. Tax. I did it by editing

```
amount/default.phtml
```

and changing

```
$block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()
```

above the span. But, now i want to display label on it. When i use

```
$block->getPriceDisplayLabel()
```

i get "Incl. Tax", but instead, i want to show first "Excl. Tax". So how can i access both of the labels as i want?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<!-- excluding tax price -->
<?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
    <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- including tax price -->
<span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
    <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
    data-price-amount="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>"
    data-price-type="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceType() ?>"
    class="price-wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceWrapperCss() ?>"
><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?></span>
```